# How to avoid lambda implicit conversion to return type Unit when passed as a function parameter?

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-inference

Given a wrapper type, eg `Promise<T>`, how to write a type safe `resolve(block: () -> T)` method where `Promise<Unit>().resolve{ getInt() }` doesn't compile.

While an `() -> T` expression is not assignable to `() -> Unit`, somehow, only when passing it as a function parameter, an implicit conversion occurs.

How to disable this implicit conversion? It is causing issues where the lambda writer expects a value to be stored, but the promise type is `Unit`, and the lambda is implicitly converted to `() -> Unit` and the value lost.

This is specific to `kotlin.Unit` as defining a custom `Unit` (eg: `object Unit2`) doesn't exhibit the same issue. I could not find this special case in the [Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html#smart-casts).

Full example:

```
class Promise<T> {
  fun resolve(block: () -> T) {}
}

fun getInt() = 1
fun doSomething() {}

fun test() {
  Promise<Int>().resolve{ 1 } // ok
  Promise<Double>().resolve{ 2 } // doesn't compile, as expected
  Promise<Unit>().resolve{ doSomething() } // ok
  Promise<Unit>().resolve{ getInt() } // compile! but should not
}
```

I've tried using `@kotlin.internal.NoInfer`, but it only works if the receiver is `T`, not a wrapper around it (`Wrapper<T>`).

For more context, this is for a type safe wrapper to React Native's `Promise.resolve(Object)`.

Comment: The thing is, it runs perfectly, because the lambda is still valid. The result of `getInt()` will just be ignored. Because the language does not enforce *return* in lambdas, it is totally free to ignore the last statement return value if the caller expects Unit as a result. You can verify that: if you enforce return value like this: `Promise<Unit>().resolve { return@resolve getInt() }`, then you will get a compilation error.

Comment: I'm not saying the behavior is unsound, just that it is error prone and confusing. There are many safe things that are not allowed, for example functions expressions are not covariant on their output. Why is there a special case for Unit and how can I avoid it?

Comment: It is confusing for some, but not for everyone. You have a very valid use-case, but still, if the compiler was enforcing lambda return value from last expression, some users could tell the other way around "why is the compiler not clever enough to just ignore my return value". This looks like the kind of case that has to be clarified by the official Kotlin team. I think this is an area they're still working on. Have you looked at this potentially related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12719 ?